# Android: SQLite, small issue with inserting and query

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, insert

I am developing my first application which contains an SQLite database, containing table `ANIMAL` which has the columns `_id`, `animal_name`, `animal_bio`.

The user is presented with animal names in a ListView; selecting an animal will bring him/her to a page where he/she can view the animals bio.

The problem I'm having is:

When I add the bio of each animal to the DB - no errors.
However, running the app causes the ListView (previously working) to display a blank screen.

My Insertion code:

```
public long populateDB(){       
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    long[] rowIds = new long[animalName.length];

    // Populate the animal table
    for(int i = 0; i < animalName.length; i++){
        initialValues.put(KEY_ANIMALNAME, animalName[i]);
        initialValues.put(KEY_BIOGRAPHY, bio[i]);
        rowIds[i] = qmDB.insert(ANIMAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
    return rowIds[0];
}
```

And the create database statement

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
            "create table " + ANIMAL_TABLE +
            " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + 
            "animal_name text not null, " +
            "biography text not null);";
```

I cannot see anything wrong with this code, so if anyone has any suggestions, I'd be very grateful.

EDIT: Retrieving animals code

```
public Cursor retrieveAnnimals(){
    return qmDB.query(ANIMAL_TABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_ANIMALNAME,
            },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            ORDER_BY_NAME);
}
```

Calling the create and insert from application, this takes place in the ListActivity, called ListAnimals:

```
dbm = new MyDBManager();
dbm.open();
dbm.deleteTable();
dbm.populateTable();
myCursor = dbm.retrieveAnimals();
```

Comment: does it store values in DB? put up your code where you retrieve animal rows from DB. that may help.

Comment: Hi Priyank, yes the Database does store the values, I have edited the code with retrieving animals code.

Comment: Could you collaborate on when it happens? I guess you start the app, all animals are shown. Clicking an animal, adding a bio to it and returning to the list of animals only displays a blank list?

Comment: Hey Pecka, the blank list occurs when the list is first to be displayed.I have the problem narrowed down to the insert statement - i replaced the original insert with an insertOrThrow() and it is throwing an error on database creation.

Comment: @Jnanathan Okay, so database hasn't been created when you call insert?  Where/how are you creating your database?

Comment: Pecka, I have updated the original post with this code.The database is created and populated all before the insert takes place.As I said, it all worked fine, until it came to adding the biography feature, which is causing all the problems!

Comment: Can you check your your cursor is blank or not. If not blank then post your code of list view where you bind your list view.

Comment: new String[] {
            KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_ANIMALNAME,
            } remove last comma as new String[] {
            KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_ANIMALNAME
            }

Comment: Hi pankaj this was not the problem - I have narrowed the problem down to it being in the populateDB() method.I have used an insertOrThrow() and it works fine when I do not add the bio info, but throws an error when I try to add it..